# Another python unicode error

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I'm getting errors such as

```
UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'\x01\xff \xfeJ a z z', 1, 2, 'ordinal not in range(128)'
```

I'm also getting sequences such as

```
u'\x17\x01\xff \xfeA r t   B l a k e y'
```

I recognize \x01\xff\xfe as a BOM, but how do I transform these into the obvious output (Jazz and Art Blakey)?

These are coming from a program that reads music file tags.

I've tried various encodings, such a s.encode('utf8'), and various decodes followed by encodes, without success.

As requested:

```
from hsaudiotag import auto
inf = 'test.mp3'
song = auto.File(inf)
print song.album, song.artist, song.title, song.genre

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "audio2.py", line 4, in
> <module>
>     print song.album, song.artist, song.title, song.genre   File "C:\program files\python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
>     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map) UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xfe' in
> position 4 : character maps to <undefined>
```

If I change the print statement to

```
with open('x', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(song.genre)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "audio2.py", line 6, in <module>
    f.write(song.genre)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xff' in position 1:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: It might help to show your code as from where you get the raw byte input to the point where you get this error. And show the whole stacktrace.

Comment: The unicode is direct output from running a music file tag reading program called hsaudiotag. The error is generated by a print or write statement. I also get UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xff' in position 1:
ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Please do exactly what I have asked of you. I don't care what this is output from.

Comment: I would report this as a bug in hsaudiotag; those values should *never* be decoded that way.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I was hoping I was missing some unicode issue. Alas, hsaudiotag is much better for my purposes than the alternatives and does not seem to be actively maintained. I suppose get rid of the initial hex chars and the spaces

Comment: it looks like hsaudiotag output incorrect tags, for '\x01\xff \xfeJ a z z' is not a valid utf16 string. it's valid only when \xff\xfe is the leading sequence of a string.

Comment: Based on the two examples (u'\x01\xff \xfeJ a z z' and  '\x01\xff \xfeJ a z z'), what would be the easiest way to transform these into valid strings? Eliminate the bytes before \xff, eliminate the space between \xff and \xfe, then str.encode('utf16')?

Comment: This looks broken beyond recovery. The zero bytes have somehow been replaced with spaces, and there is a zero byte in the middle of the BOM—which means the frame has been read without being properly desynchronised. Have you checked the file with another (known-good) tag reader so you can be sure whether it's a bug in hsaudiotag as opposed to just bad tags?

Comment: I've now installed mutagen, which works fine and is not nearly as complex as I had remembered. I had checked the files with mp3tag, foobar2000 and itunes.

Answer (score 0):

For your actual question, you need to write bytes, not characters, to files. Call:

```
f.write(song.genre.encode('utf-8'))
```

and you won't get the error. You can use `io.open` to get a character stream that you can write to with the encoding done automatically, ie:

```
with io.open('x', 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(song.genre)
```

Getting Unicode to the Console can be a matter of some difficulty (under Windows in particular)—see [PrintFails](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails).

However, as discussed in the comments, what you've got doesn't look like a working tag value... it looks more like an mangled ID3v2 frame data block, which it might not be possible to recover. I don't know if this is a bug in your tag reading library or you just have a file with rubbish tags.

Comment: While I don't get an error with that, the result is 'Ã¿ Ã¾J a z z' (or '\x01\xc3\xbf \xc3\xbeJ a z z') which is not much better. The bug appears to be in the tag library, as discussed in the comments.